# Pinvoke issue in visual C# with C++ code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, kinect, 3d-reconstruction

I'm trying to code the "One-minute" example of reconstructMe SDK, however their SDK is in c++ I think, I succesfully created a console application as directed on their page ([here](http://reconstructme.net/wp-content/uploads/ReconstructMe/1.2/doc/html/_getting_started_page.html#OneMinuteExample)), but I want to create a simple UI, however I'm not very familiar with Visual c++ (I do know something about c++), so I tried their example for C# (I'm pretty much familiar with their UI design) but I get this error when using the C# code provided ([here](http://reconstructme.net/wp-content/uploads/ReconstructMe/1.1/doc/html/example_reconstructmesdk_one_minute_8cs-example.html)):

> A call to PInvoke function 'Lala!Lala.Reme::reme_context_compile' has
>   unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that
>   the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match
>   the target unmanaged signature.

I think is an issue of configuring the project or something like that.

Comment: Did you ensure that your C# project is compiling x86?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reconstructMe DLL is using the C [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) (`Cdecl`) and not the Windows calling convention (`StdCall`).  They differ in how the stack is handled, which is why having an incorrect calling convention results in a stack imbalance.

The default for p/Invoke is `StdCall`, you need to manually set the [CallingConvension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx) parameter to `Cdecl` on the `DllImport` attribute:

```
[DllImport("example.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int function(int param);
```

Comment: Interesting, we don't have the CallingConvention attribute set on our example and it just works fine for us. Thanks for pointing this out though, will update the example.